# average/weighted average within Excel

Tags: average

```
5 star    128
4 star    17
3 star    10
2 star    2
1 star    14

Average stars 4.42
```

How many more 5 stars would I need to get `Average Stars` to 4.45 or 4.47 etc.

So what I tried was using SUMPRODUCT in Excel but I am approaching this wrong. First of all I cannot achieve the current number 4.42 because of my incorrect approach.

I would like to be able to change the variables at my discretion and see the outcome

how would I continue?

Comment: Let $n$ number of $5$ starts are needed

So, the average will be  $$=\frac{128+17+10+2+14+128\cdot n}{n+5}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thanks, I need this to return a number like 4.42 for a visual aid, this doesn't give me an indication of what the current average star is when I change variables, this is very close though

Comment: @labbhattacharjee:  No, the average is not that.

Comment: @RossMillikan, it depends on the context.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee:  the $128$ votes need to be weighted by $5$ etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $S=128 \cdot 5 + 17 \cdot 4 + 10 \cdot 3 + 2 \cdot 2 + 14 \cdot 1$ and $N=128+17+10+2+14$  Your current average is $A=\frac SN=\frac {128 \cdot 5 + 17 \cdot 4 + 10 \cdot 3 + 2 \cdot 2 + 14 \cdot 1}{128+17+10+2+14}$.  If you want your average to be $A'$ from the addition of $n\ 5$'s, you need $A'=\frac {S+5n}{N+n}$.  You can solve this for $n$ as all the other values are given.  $A'(N+n)=S+5n, n=\frac {A'N-S}{5-A'}$

Comment: yes, this worked for me, thank you